# Wine spec files

Tags: dll, wine, winelib

I have a Windows DLL called `morag.dll` containing functions foo and bar. I also have a Linux SO called `morag.so` containing the Linux implementations of foo and bar (same parameters on each platform). I have a Windows application that loads `morag.dll` that I want to run under wine. The application itself runs fine, however I need to create the mapping between foo and bar which are expected by my application to be found in `morag.dll` to instead use foo and bar in `morag.so`.

To do this I know I need to create `morag.dll.spec` file and winebuild it into `morag.dll.so`.

Following instructions [here](https://www.winehq.org/docs/winelib-guide/bindlls) I created a wrapper in `morag.c` containing functions `Proxyfoo` and `Proxybar` which do nothing more than call real functions foo and bar. Then I created `morag.dll.spec` thus:-

```
1 stdcall foo (long ptr) Proxyfoo
2 stdcall bar (ptr ptr)  Proxybar
```

I compiled my c part, winebuild the spec file, and then use winegcc to link them into `morag.dll.so`

Then I read [this page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib_User%27s_Guide) which suggested you maybe didn't need the proxy function so I tried without the c part altogether and made a spec file thus:-

```
1 stdcall foo (long ptr)
2 stdcall bar (ptr ptr)
```

And as above, did the winebuild step and the winegcc link step.

In both cases these were the options I used.

```
winebuild --dll -m32 -E ./morag.dll.spec -o morag.dll.o

ldopts= -m32 -fPIC -shared -L/usr/lib/wine -L/opt/morag/lib -lmorag

winegcc $(ldopts) -z muldefs -o morag.dll.so [morag.o] morag.dll.o
```

N.B. [..] denotes I only used this in the case where I was also building the c part.

in both cases, when my application running under wine tries to load the entry point in the DLL using `GetProcAddress` it fails.

I ran wine with `WINEDEBUG=+module,+relay` and saw the attempt and failure recorded as follows:-

```
0025:Ret  KERNEL32.LoadLibraryExA() retval=7dbc0000 ret=00447b84
0025:Call KERNEL32.GetProcAddress(7dbc0000,00b2d060 "foo") ret=00447c8a
0025:Ret  KERNEL32.GetProcAddress() retval=00000000 ret=00447c8a
```

It seems it has found and loaded my `morag.dll.so` since `LoadLibraryExA` has returned the handle to it, but when it tries to find function foo within that HMODULE handle it fails.

If I issue:-

```
nm -D morag.dll.so
```

I see foo and bar shown as U in both cases. In the case where there are proxy functions as well, the proxy functions are shown as T.

I assume that this is because I have not built the `morag.dll.so` file correctly, either with the wrong options, or that my spec file is not correctly formed. I am not sure which of the two schemes described above I should be using.

All help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today.

What was missing in my case was the proper exporting rule for e.g. `foo` and `bar` in the built-in DLL. Conveniently, besides the `--dll` object, the `winebuild` tool can create a .def file for us, e.g.:

```
morag.def: morag.spec
    $(WINEBUILD) --def -E $< -o $@
```

The resulting .def file must be linked into morag.dll.so along with other objects. This does the job.

Comment: Note this question is more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380191/wine-cant-load-my-custom-build-in-dll-and-report-call-to-unimplemented-functio for which the same answer could be helpful.